# What would be the best implementation of the D'Hondt method of highest averages for allocating seats on party-list proportional representation?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, algorithm

The [2019 European Parliament elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_European_Parliament_election) are happening shortly and seat allocation will use the [D'Hondt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method) of highest averages. In order to analyse possible scenarios and results I need a *Wolfram Language* implementation of the algorithm.

Given a list of votes and an integer number of seats available
**what would be a *good* Mathematica implementation of the algorithm to determine the seats allocated to each party?**

The basic algorithm is ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method#Allocation))

> After all the votes have been tallied, successive quotients are
>   calculated for each party. The party with the largest quotient wins
>   one seat, and its quotient is recalculated. This is repeated until the
>   required number of seats is filled. The formula for the quotient is ($V$: total number of votes, $s$: number of seats that party has been allocated so far, initially $0$ for all parties.)

$\text{quotient} = \frac{V}{s+1}$

We want to define

```
DHondt[v_List, s_Integer]
```

The expected outcome is:

```
votes = {100000, 80000, 30000, 20000};
DHondt[votes , 8]
(* {4, 3, 1, 0} *)
```

I'm basically sharing my implementation here and inviting (challenging?) others to improve in elegance or performance. There is a published solution [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iZTxaxT_YeMC&lpg=PA928&ots=96BwKCFvD8&dq=DHondt%20%22mathematica%22&pg=PA928#v=onepage&q=DHondt%20%22mathematica%22&f=false), but I think we can do better.

Comment: Great question. [You may be interested in this tangentially-related WTC talk.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmIJctA2fVU&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0VeBoNETYfeiHxsX0i-Dbl&index=7)

Answer (score 2):

This will work with data in form of [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) or [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)

```
ClearAll[DHondt$iter, DHondt ];
DHondt$iter[LV_][LC_] := MapAt[(# + 1) &, LC, Ordering[LV/(LC + 1), -1]];
DHondt[v_List, s_Integer] := Nest[DHondt$iter[v], Array[0 &, Length[v]], s];
DHondt[v_Association, s_Integer] := AssociationThread[Keys[v], DHondt[Values[v], s]]

votesAssoc = <|
  "Red Party" -> 100000,
  "Green Party" -> 80000,
  "Blue Party" -> 30000,
  "Violet Party" -> 20000
  |>
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]